# How to subscribe to an Observable that emits in some other part of the code?

Tags: android, observable, rx-java

I'm sort of a beginner on RxJava. I have the following issue.
I have a `Presenter` and a `Fragment`. I'm creating the Presenter inside `onCreate` of the Fragment. 
I want to subscribe to an `Observable` in the Presenter's constructor. And this Observable should emit when the Fragment's `onViewCreated` fires (which calls some method in the Presenter - i.e. `onViewReady`).
The issue I'm running into is that when I create the Observable (in the Presenter's constructor), I also have to pass the emitter then. How can I subscribe to the observable in the constructor and emit later inside `onViewReady`?

I tried searching bunch of StackOverflow and Medium links. All of them seem to always pass the emitter during Observable creation.

Fragment

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // create presenter
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // call presenter.onViewReady
}
```

Presenter

```
Presenter() {
    // create and subscribe to observable
}

public void onViewReady() {
    // emit observable
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a `Observable` for this, it seems you are trying to use RxJava for the sake of it, and really just makes the code more complicated and less readable - the fragment methods are already callback methods - the work is done for you ..

Comment: @MarkKeen The question is part of a bigger issue, which requires me to implement this behaviour. I didn't mention other parts of the problem to keep it simple.

Comment: Unfortunately you've not said this and your entire question is centralised around one concrete implementation (code and explanation), so not sure how I'm supposed to know otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using a Subject?

Fragment Code:

```
public Subject<Integer> subject = PublishSubject.create()

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    presenter = new Presenter(subject);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    subject.onNext(1);
}
```

Presenter Code:

```
Presenter(Subject<Integer> subject) {
    subject.doOnNext(i -> onViewReay()).subscribe();
}

public void onViewReady() {
    // code here...
}
```

I hope the syntax is good, as I did this without android studio. also. I would suggest using a disposable to make sure you dispose the subscription on fragment destroy.

and I only tried this in RxJava2. so if you are using RxJava1 some additional adjustments may be needed.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about `Subject`. Using it as an observable did the trick

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you could achieve that:

```
private final Observable<MyClass> myObservable;

Presenter() {
    // create observable
    myObservable = Observable.create(new Action1<Emitter<MyClass>>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Emitter<MyClass> emitter) {
            // Emit here
            emitter.onNext(...);
            emitter.onNext(...);

            emitter.onCompleted();
        }
    });
}

public void onViewReady() {
    // subscribe to the observable
    myObservable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers::mainThread)
                .subscribe(
                        new Action1<MyClass>() {
                            @Override
                            public void call(MyClass mc) {
                                // TODO implement
                            }
                        },
                        new Action1<Throwable>() {
                            @Override
                            public void call(Throwable throwable) {
                                // TODO implement
                            }
                        }
                );
}
```